# ansible win_user, create is fine, but replaying playbook fails

Tags: ansible

I am able to create a user on a windows server as part of a playbook, but when the playbook is re-run, the create task fails.

I'm trying to work out if I am missing something.

playbook:

```
---
# vim: set filetype=ansible ff=unix ts=2 sw=2 ai expandtab :
#
# Playbook to configure the environment

- hosts: createuser

  tasks:
    - name: create user
      run_once: true
      win_user:
        name: gary
        password: 'B0bP4ssw0rd123!^'
        password_never_expires: true
        account_disabled: no
        account_locked: no
        password_expired: no
        state: present
        groups:
          - Administrators
          - Users
```

if I run the playbook when the user does not exist, the create works fine.

When I re-run, I get:

```
PLAY [createuser] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dsy-demo-mssql02]

TASK [create user] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [dsy-demo-mssql02]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Exception calling \"ValidateCredentials\" with \"2\" argument(s): \"The network path was not found.\r\n\""}
```

I have verified that I can logon to the server using the created user credentials.

Anyone seen this before, or understand what can be happening?

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, I've moved this query out to the ansible project itself:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24884

Answer (score -2):

It looks to me like it might be the

```
     run_once: true
```

is only telling the task to run once. For the ansible documentation on that delegation you can go here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `run_once`. `run_once` executes task every playbook run but only for one host.